# Why are these branch lines marked partial?

Tags: language-agnostic, code-coverage

I have these lines marked partial, why is it?

[image]
[Full coverage report](https://codecov.io/gh/felipe-lavratti/reacto/src/ae310b4177472e8f3b876e53674071ab9acd5192/reacto/includes/reacto/reusables/signal_slot.template#L140)

What does those coverage numbers mean? How came you have 2 hits of the branch content, while the branch itself marks 3/4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gcov report the branch coverage is as follows:

`30:  140:    if (obj->root)
branch  0 taken 11% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 89%
branch  2 taken 0% (fallthrough)
branch  3 taken 100%`

> [Raw upload](https://codecov.s3.amazonaws.com/v4/raw/2016-12-22/B408B7362596F138AB123EBB23C4D753/ae310b4177472e8f3b876e53674071ab9acd5192/957170fa-cbd4-4c47-af68-5d4a3f373579.txt) found in the Codecov Commit's **Build** tab.

In compiled languages there could be multiple execution strategies. In this case there are 4. Codecov detects all branches, as you can see in the coverage report above, there is not much other data to go off.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but, what these data mean? I see where the 3/4 is comming now, what about the percentages and the `taken` and the `falltrough` ? Which is the branch 2 that were never taken?

Comment: Great question. Codecov does not have any documentation on how gcov works and collects branch data. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060005/understanding-branches-in-gcov-files